# I am trying to add an expandable 'Read More' tag in my Wordpress Theme (for other pages)

Tags: php, wordpress

so I have a website running on Wordpress. My theme doesn't allow the use of the existing "Read More" tag available in Wordpress. Hence, I would need to do it manually on the script. I have checked all the earlier posts on Stackflow and most of the Read More solution shows to link to other pages. But here I am trying to an expandable Read More tag so that the balance texts can be seen by customers.

Here is my piece of code that I will need to add the Read More tag :

```
' <?php
                echo '<div class="jerseys-description mt-0 mb-10">';
                if (!empty($description)) { 
                    echo '<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            '.apply_filters('the_content',$description).'
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
                if(!empty($short_description)) { 
                    //echo '<div class="term-content">'.$short_description.'</div>';?>
                    
                <?php }
   ?>'
```

And what I have done is to rewrite the apply filters using wp-trims functions

```
''. $auto_excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', wp_trim_words( $description, 100, "Read More" ) ).'           
<div class="read-more"><a>Read More</a></div>'
```

But this doesnt give me the expected results, this link to other page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear - what exactly are you trying to do? e.g. what text should be displayed and what should be in the expanded section? Also you haven't included any show/hide code to implement the expanding. Note that the excerpt and the description are different things, so if you want to use both then you need to include them both in your main code. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help

Answer (score 0):

I gess you're trying to get the "Read more" link after the content using the wp_trim_words function.
I'm not an expert but what I did in Genesis worked for me.
Just write the link code inside wp_trim_words function. As I said it worked for me.

```
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 25, '...<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="read-more-link">Read more</a>' );
```

I hope I helped you... or anyone.